# Executing price of items depending on what checkbutton is clicked on in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, tkinter

[Image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQfra.png)  I am currently creating a gui for my college class displaying 5 pizzas to choose from in the form of checkbuttons. How can I display the price of pizzas depending on what checkbuttons are clicked? I can display the prices using multiple if statements. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way then writing 15 lines of if statement? Is there a more efficient way such as creating a for loop then providing if statments in the for loop? [image of code involving if statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezvHk.png)

Comment: Don't post code in image.  Better copy the code as text into the question so others can copy and paste the code for testing.  Also the posted code is better a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

OK, have a list of lists (you need to get syntax right):

```
_list = [['cheese',5],[pepperoni,7]....]
checkboxes = []
labels = []
for i in range 5:
    checkboxes.append(checkbox(frame,text = _list[i][0]))
    labels.append(label(frame,text=_list[i][1]))
    checkboxes[i].grid(column=0,row=i)
    labels[i].grid(column=1,row=i)

(add a button to start calculation)
total = 0
def calculate(event):
   for i in range(5)
       if get(checkboxes[i]) :
           total = total + _list[i][1]
```

Ok, I left you plenty of work to get this to work, but hopefully this gives you an alternative algorithm

Comment: This is one way for me to implement a button with a function in my program. I have to have 3 buttons in project. I have submit total, pretending as if they are submitting there order, and calculating price button, pretending as if they want to know prices of a pizza or multiple pizzas.

Comment: I have used the for loop to create each button with it's own value. How would I create a function stating to display the onvalues of only the checkbuttons clicked (price of each pizza)? Also, what do you mean by "if get(checkboxes[i]"? I don't believe that's valid syntax.